# How do I expose custom control events and properties in MainWindow.xaml where my custom control is inside a User Control?

Tags: wpf, events, properties, user-controls, custom-controls

I am stuck in a situation where my custom control has one `Text` property and an event handler registered with a button in `OnApplyTemplate` method.

But when I put this custom control inside a user control and than I use this user control in a window where I am trying to access Custom control `Text` dependency property but not able to do so. Also trying to Fire click event from the button which is inside custom control, but when I click on the button the event does not fire. Nothing happens.

If anyone has found the similar problem and have resolved and know any solution to this .

How can I access the dependency property of custom control which is inside a user control which is used inside a `Mainwindow.xaml`? I want to access the properties and events of custom control inside `Mainwindow.xaml`.

Answer (score 0):

To get to properties of custom control which is inside a user control which is used inside a `Mainwindow.xaml` make properties in this case type of `string` (for `Text`) and apply in user control your new property to this one in ur custom control.

To handle an event u can make in your custom control your own event handler like this

`public event MyEventHandler;`

u need delegate as well

`public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, ChoosenIdsEventArgs e);`

and then in custom control on Click event of button write

```
  protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   if(MyEventHandler != null)//check if u have this handler invoke on parent (user control in this case)
   {
       MyEventHandler(sender,e);
   }
  }
```

same thing can you do on your user control.

hope this help:)

Comment: thanks harry180 , i have created further dependency property in userocntrol for text property of custom control, i am able to access it in main window too, but the problem is with the event, I have registered the click event to Part_ClearButton custom template  -- public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            Button clearFilterButton = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_ClearSearchBoxButton") as Button;

            if (clearFilterButton != null)
            { clearFilterButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ClearFilterButton_Click);}}

Comment: why do you register this event to template? Will you using it by plenty of diffrent buttons?